# How to run hidden R task?

Tags: c#, r, windows, command-line

I'm calling Rscript.exe from c# windows forms app, and the cmd window opens up for a few milliseconds. The python solution was easy: simply started pythonw.exe instead of python.exe

Here is the function:

```
private void runr()
    {
        orig = richTextBox1.Text;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\cp.R", richTextBox1.Text);
        string cmd = @"C:\cp.R";
        string args = @"";
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\Rscript.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                StreamReader reader2 = process.StandardError;
                string err = reader2.ReadToEnd();
                richTextBox1.Text = result;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(err))
                    richTextBox1.Text += "\nError:\n" + err;
            }
        }
    }
```

Setting `start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) to `true`. This prevents the system from creating a console window for the new process.